# How to force category to products relationship in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a database, where I want to accomplish this sitaution:
I have a Category table, and Products table.
I want to make it impossible to add a product without an existing category assigned to it (I believe I did that with the FK on the Products table).
I want to force DELETE on a Category, to DELETE all the children (products) assigned to that category.
I DONT want a category to be deleted, if/when ALL the products belonging to it are deleted.

Currently, what I've come up with is this:
http://codepad.org/eSGqtyOs

I am unsure, one guy says the FK on the Categories table, will prevent me from adding categories without a product (catch 22..), and if I add On delete CASCADE in the product table, it will automatically delete a Category, once the last product in that category is deleted...

Please help to get this straight and right.

Also, please do not try to convince me to keep old categories/products not "sold" anymore - I have my reasons, I know the requirements I have for this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your requirements, you don't need the FK in categories (referencing products). In fact, the way you made these FKs circular, you won't be able to insert *any* data due to the chicken-and-egg problem.

You **only** need FK in products (referencing categories).

> I want to make it impossible to add a product without an existing category assigned to it (I believe I did that with the FK on the Products table).

That's right.

> I want to force DELETE on a Category, to DELETE all the children (products) assigned to that category.

ON DELETE CASCADE should take care of that.

> I DONT want a category to be deleted, if/when ALL the products belonging to it are deleted.

A FK allows a child-less parent.

So in your case, the FK on products referencing categories will allow a category to exist without having any products.